# Polygon clipping with percentage tile membership

Tags: raster, shapefile, polygon, overlay, rioxarray

Let me setup the problem: I have a tiled world map (0.1° x 0.1°) with values assigned to each tile. I want to assign the values to each country, and I'm doing so by clipping to their ZEE mask. But clip only allows me to either -include all tiles that touch the ZEE polygon mask (all_touched=True) or -exclude them(all_touched=False). So I'm either counting all border tiles double or I'm not accounting for them.

What I would like to do is assign the percentage of value of the tile that is inside the country (kind of like what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464829/how-to-calculate-what-percentage-of-a-pixel-is-within-the-bounds-of-a-shape))

Do you know how one can do that with Rioxarray?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html ?